# Encrypt an entire table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, security

I've just received a question from my boss to encrypt an entire table, stored in SQL Server 2012.

The problem is that, in this table, we store some personal information that not even the database administrator has to see. We have also several application which work with the data in this table, so I will appreciate if there is a method to hide the data both with ODBC access and with SQL Query Access via SQL Server Management Studio, without changing these applications.

Can anyone tells me the solution?
Thank you very much

Comment: is your encryption technique simple?

Comment: I can choose the encryption technique, so I can keep it simple as i want!

Comment: Encryption isn't a magic wand that transforms data from "unsafe" to "safe". You need to pick appropriate tools based on your *threat model*. As a first step, if encryption is even what's required here, you ought to review whether solutions built into SQL Server will be adequate. And the requirement to not change existing applications is troubling since it means the server *has* to be capable of decrypting the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict access to certain columns only you can use column level security and grant access only to those columns. Considering you have a group called ODBCAPPS it would looks something like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Employee (EmployeeID, FirstName, MiddleName, SurName) TO ODBCAPPS;
```

More details about GRANT you can find on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something with ASCII

```
UPDATE Table_name
SET x=ASCII(x)+3, y=ASCII(Y)+3 // Choose your number. This is the simplest
```

For more refer :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql

Comment: Please make sure that you are using NVARCHAR datatype; As ASCII(Z)+3 = ] ; Which cannot be stored in VARCHAR datatype.

Comment: This is only encryption if the assumed attacker is your kid sister. It also, obviously, destroys all existing data save for the leftmost character.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Please refer the comments in the question - He says - "I can choose the encryption technique, so I can keep it simple as i want" - this is the simplest thing I found

Comment: Maybe so, but most people in the 21st century asking for encryption wouldn't be expecting something that's been broken for centuries nor (as I indicated) where it's actually destroying most of the data unrecoverably.

Comment: And it breaks the requirement of "not changing the applications".

Comment: If you can elobrate @SMor